# Is it possible to get taller after 25?

Tags: exercise, health

I'm 25 years old and will become 26 in few months. I'm 173cm, is it possible to still get height with certain exercises?

Note that I'm 75KGs with 7KGs as extra weight and now I'm working out to lose that fat.

Comment: Possible? Maybe. If your growth plates haven't closed, then yes it's possible. At 26 however, it's highly unlikely unless you have one of a few different growth abnormalities. If you are really worried, talk to a doctor and have your growth plates x-rayed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely to me that your body would actually still grow vertically at that age.

However, if you have bad posture (such as a hunched back, or a office-job crooked neck), and you target this issue by doing exercises, you might eventually find yourself standing more upright than before, and therefore appear to be taller, even though your body hasn't actually grown taller.